# Customized Xforms trigger with image

Tags: xforms, xforms-betterform

I'm trying to create a Xforms processor and I really don't understand what to do with triggers which need to display an image insthead of a text. [The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-xforms20-20120807/#The_load_Element) does not provide such detail, but I found [an Open Book](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/XForms/Controlling_Button_Appearance) with this example:

```
<xf:trigger appearance="xf:image">
    <img src="XForms-button.jpg" />
    <xf:message level="modal" ev:event="DOMActivate">Image 
    clicked</xf:message>
    <xf:hint>This hint text comes up if you hover over a button.</xf:hint>
</xf:trigger>
```

But as the standard doesn't mention, and the img tag is html -not defined in xforms-, I'm wondering if it is right. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this is to use a CSS background image for the trigger or better the resulting button. A look into the browser source should reveal how to match the element you want. If you're using betterform as the tag suggests you can write a rule like this

```
#mytrigger .xfValue{
  background-image:url....
```

You must give the trigger the id 'mytrigger' for this to work.

Another option that should work for betterFORM:

```
<xf:trigger id="trigger1" ref="trigger1/value" src="images/bf_logo_67x27.png">
      <xf:label></xf:label>
</xf:trigger>
```